# Errors during boot and fan is always running after installing graphics drivers from the AMD website

Tags: radeon, inspiron

I have a Radeon HD 6470 in my Inspiron N5110 laptop. The problem is that I can't make my VGA work properly. Also there is a continuous increase in the temperature of the VGA and the fan is always running. I read something about the overheating, but honestly I really need  help.

When I installed the drivers for AMD graphics cards from the official AMD website, I couldn't start Ubuntu which always displayed some kind of error in the startup.

Answer (score 1):

This link worked for me:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1893523

I tried it on ubuntu 32 and 64 bits, achieving a successful installation

You start from the boot option from the installation CD, with the code "nomodeset" as described in the link.

Good Luck!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.